# Interrogate the C compiler about data types when cross-compiling

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, configure, autotools

I am working on a cross-platform project that uses GNU Autotools for the build system, and I was wondering if there is a way to run a simple `sizeof(int)` and pass the result to the `configure` script (or even simply to the standard output) **when cross-compiling**.

Let's imagine I am using a 32-bit machine for compiling a program for a 64-bit machine. If my compiler is able to compile code for a different architecture it means that surely knows the result of `sizeof(int)` *on the target architecture*.

My question is: How do I interrogate the compiler for obtaining that information when cross-compiling?

### EDIT

As Ian Abbott has explained in the comments, there is a [`AX_COMPILE_CHECK_SIZEOF()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_compile_check_sizeof.html) macro in the [Autoconf Archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/index.html) able to compute `sizeof()` *via compile checks* (not run checks) that therefore works when cross-compiling. Unfortunately the macro is not able to deal with expressions that contain non-alphanumeric characters (like, for example, `sizeof(sizeof(char))`, where `sizeof(char)` contains round brackets), so [I have published](https://github.com/madmurphy/not-autotools/) a fork of it that optionally allows to give alphanumeric “labels” to the checks, to be used as valid variable names:

```
dnl  NA_SANITIZE_VARNAME(string)
dnl  **************************************************************************
dnl
dnl  Replaces `/\W/g,` with `'_'` and `/^\d/` with `_\0`
dnl
dnl  From: not-autotools/m4/not-autotools.m4
dnl
dnl  **************************************************************************
AC_DEFUN([NA_SANITIZE_VARNAME],
    [m4_if(m4_bregexp(m4_normalize([$1]), [[0-9]]), [0], [_])[]m4_translit(m4_normalize([$1]),
        [ !"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^`{|}~],
        [__________________________________])])


dnl  NC_CC_CHECK_SIZEOF(data-type[, headers[, store-as[, extra-sizes]]])
dnl  **************************************************************************
dnl
dnl  Checks for the size of `data-type` using **compile checks**, not run
dnl  checks.
dnl
dnl  From: https://github.com/madmurphy/not-autotools/blob/master/m4/not-cc.m4
dnl
dnl  **************************************************************************
AC_DEFUN([NC_CC_CHECK_SIZEOF], [
    m4_pushdef([__label__],
        NA_SANITIZE_VARNAME([sizeof_]m4_tolower(m4_ifblank([$3],
            [[$1]], [[$3]]))))
    AC_MSG_CHECKING([size of `$1`])
    AC_CACHE_VAL([ac_cv_]__label__, [
        # List sizes in rough order of prevalence.
        for nc_sizeof in 4 8 1 2 16 m4_normalize([$4]) ; do
            AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([
                AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[$2]], [[
                    switch (0) {
                        case 0:
                        case (sizeof ($1) ==
                            ${nc_sizeof}):;
                    }
                ]])
            ],
                [AS_VAR_COPY([ac_cv_]__label__, [nc_sizeof])])
            AS_IF([test "x${ac_cv_]__label__[}" != x], [break;])
        done
    ])
    AS_IF([test "x${ac_cv_]__label__[}" = x], [
        AC_MSG_RESULT([??])
        AC_MSG_ERROR([cannot determine a size for $1])
    ])
    AC_MSG_RESULT([${ac_cv_]__label__[}])
    AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED(m4_toupper(m4_quote(__label__)),
        [${ac_cv_]__label__[}],
        [The number of bytes in type $1])
    m4_ifnblank([$3],
        [AS_VAR_COPY([na_]m4_quote(m4_tolower([$3])), [nc_sizeof])])
    m4_popdef([__label__])
])
```

With this version we can use, for example, a `size_t` label for the expression `sizeof(sizeof(char))`:

```
NC_CC_CHECK_SIZEOF([sizeof(char)], [], [size_t])
```

By doing so, `NC_CC_CHECK_SIZEOF()` will export a shell variable named `${ac_cv_sizeof_size_t}` within the `configure` script and a preprocessor macro named `SIZEOF_SIZE_T` within the C environment, both containing the expansion of `sizeof(sizeof(char))`.

#### Autoconf's native `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF()` macro

As Brett has pointed out in the comments, there is a native [`AC_CHECK_SIZEOF()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Generic-Compiler-Characteristics.html#AC_005fCHECK_005fSIZEOF) macro that apparently doesn't seem to limit the computed size to the powers of 2 (plus the manually-provided sizes), as [`AX_COMPILE_CHECK_SIZEOF()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_compile_check_sizeof.html) does. Unfortunately, after after a quick check, I have found out that also `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF()` does not allow to pass `sizeof(char)` as argument (if I try, I get `error: AC_CHECK_SIZEOF: requires literal arguments` – the same happens if I use [Autoconf's quadrigraphs](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Quadrigraphs.html) by writing `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF([sizeof@{:@char@:}@])`).

#### Appendix – computing `CHAR_BIT` when cross-compiling

This is slightly off-topic, but since I needed it, Autoconf Archive's `AX_COMPILE_CHECK_SIZEOF()` macro inspired me to write a M4 macro that computes `CHAR_BIT` when cross-compiling (the macro does not require `limits.h` for working):

```
dnl  NC_CC_CHECK_CHAR_BIT
dnl  **************************************************************************
dnl
dnl  Calculates the size in bits of the `char` data type using compile checks
dnl
dnl  From: https://github.com/madmurphy/not-autotools/blob/master/m4/not-cc.m4
dnl
dnl  **************************************************************************
AC_DEFUN([NC_CC_CHECK_CHAR_BIT], [
    AC_MSG_CHECKING([size of `char` in bits])
    AC_CACHE_VAL([ac_cv_char_bit], [
        # Minimum size in bits for `char` is guaranteed to be 8
        for nc_char_bit in {8..64}; do
            AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([
                AC_LANG_PROGRAM(, [[
                    switch (0) {
                        case 0: case ((unsigned char)
                        (1 << ${nc_char_bit})):;
                    }
                ]])
            ], [], [break])
        done
        AS_VAR_COPY([ac_cv_char_bit], [nc_char_bit])
    ])
    AC_MSG_RESULT([${ac_cv_char_bit}])
    AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([COMPUTED_CHAR_BIT],
        [${ac_cv_char_bit}],
        [The number of bits in `char`])
])
```

After calling `NC_CC_CHECK_CHAR_BIT` (without arguments), a shell variable named `${ac_cv_char_bit}` is made available within the `configure` script and a preprocessor macro named `COMPUTED_CHAR_BIT` is made available within the C environment, both containing the size of the `char` data type measured in bits.

Comment: Even on a 64-bit machine, I'd expect `int` is 32-bit.  What platform are you using that have `int` as 64-bit?

Comment: If you're writing cross-platform code, you'd want to declare your variables and write the code to be as independent of whether it's a 32-bit or 64-bit machine as possible. For example, if you need an integer to be at most 32 bits, then you can use an `int` and no need to check what the architecture is. If you need 64 bits, then use a type that guarantees 64 bits on either platform (*e.g.*, `long long int`).

Comment: You could try the [ax_compile_check_sizeof](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_compile_check_sizeof.html) macro from the [Autoconf Archive](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/index.html). It does a compile-time check, so should work when cross compiling.

Comment: @lurker "need an integer to be at most 32 bits, then you can use an int and no need to check what the architecture is" --> An `int` is at least 16 bits,  `long` is at least 32.

Comment: Chux, `sizeof(int)` is just an example, I am not actually interested in knowing the size of an `int`, but of other data types. Lurker, agree about everything, but my program has a `configure` option for embedded systems that lets you compile the code without the C Standard Library. In that case I would like to be able to guess the best possible re-implementation of some C Standard `typedef`s for the target architecture (and relying on the standard is not an option by definition). If the `configure` script is not be able to do that the final user will have to manually edit the source code.

Comment: Ian, thank you! I will have a look at the `ax_compile_check_sizeof` macro!

Comment: Note that `ax_compile_check_sizeof` works by testing guesses at the size of the type in question.  It always includes 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16 among its guesses, but *you need to provide* any other guesses you want it to evaluate.  This makes it pretty good for standard integer, floating, and pointer types, but greatly limits its usefulness for most other types, especially structure types.

Comment: I don't quite follow the comment about reimplementing typedefs.  Do you mean you those of `stdint.h`, such as `int32_t`?  Do note that `stdint.h` is among the headers that are required to be available even when compiling for a freestanding environment.  I'm not sure whether that's what you mean by "without the C Standard Library", but that would certainly be my first guess.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the source code of the macro. I have already hacked it to make it possible to do `AX_COMPILE_CHECK_SIZEOF([typeof(sizeof(char))])`, where `sizeof(typeof(sizeof(char)))` is a synonym for `sizeof(size_t)` by the very standard definition of `size_t`, but without the need of using the header that provides the `typedef` of `size_t` (as I said in my special case I am targeting a "bare metal" architecture, no headers must be used). Fortunately the largest data type I need is `uint32_t`, so it's just perfect for my needs. I think I will soon fork an improved version of the macro.

Comment: John, the build system checks anyway that `stdint.h` is available. But even if that is not the case my code can work perfectly fine, so I am just providing a safe fallback.

Comment: An expression of `sizeof(sizeof(char))` also yields the size of `size_t` (the `sizeof` operator always returns a value of type `size_t`), no need for the GNU C keyword `typeof`. Even if passing `[sizeof(char)]` to the macro would look wrong at first glance.

Comment: @madmurphy, I'm trying to tell you that not being able to use any standard headers at all is, itself, non-standard, so I find that constraint suspicious.  I'm inclined to think you're doing unneeded work.  The standard's term for an implementation without any underlying host operating system is "freestanding implementation". C specifies several headers that are available even when building for such an implementation. These particular headers define macros and types that are characteristic of the implementation, but do not declare any functions.  `stdint.h` is among them.

Comment: John, *I am treating a non-standard case*, the user has to enable manually a `configure` option to get there. That `configure` option basically says "Hey, guys, sorry, but somehow I have to compile for a non-standard environment, help me". Otherwise my code peacefully relies on the C Standard. And even after having enabled that option, the `configure` script prudently checks for the presence of the standard `typedef`s; only as an extreme solution it implements its own `typedef`s.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica based upon the OP's post, I was assuming he's only choosing between a 32-bit and 16-bit architecture, not a 16-bit. Isn't an `int` 32 bits on a natively 32-bit architecture? But regardless, I agree a `long` would be the correct cross-platform choice, not `int`. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: nebel, good point! Thanks!

Comment: The `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF` macro works with cross-compiling. It effectively does the 'negative size' array trick, and uses a binary search to converge on the correct value.

Comment: Thank you, Brett, I didn't know about [`AC_CHECK_SIZEOF()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Generic-Compiler-Characteristics.html#AC_005fCHECK_005fSIZEOF). In the end have used a [my own fork](https://github.com/madmurphy/not-autotools) of `AX_COMPILE_CHECK_SIZEOF()` (see `m4/not-cc.m4`), modified in order to allow custom labels for the expressions computed. …Although now I can think of updating it by borrowing code from `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF()`, which seems not to limit the possible sizes to the powers of `2`…

Comment: Brett, after a check I found out that [`AC_CHECK_SIZEOF()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Generic-Compiler-Characteristics.html#AC_005fCHECK_005fSIZEOF) doesn't let me pass `sizeof(char)` as argument (I get `error: AC_CHECK_SIZEOF: requires literal arguments`). The same happens if I try to use [Autoconf's quadrigraphs](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Quadrigraphs.html) by writing `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF([sizeof@{:@char@:}@])`.

Comment: This looks like you have edited an answer into the question? Or if not, can you clarify what the question is now?

Comment: I have edited my question for including my custom fork of the `AX_COMPILE_CHECK_SIZEOF()` macro after the latter has been suggested by Ian Abbott. So yes, technically now the question contains also an answer :/

Comment: M.M. Do I have to split my edit into a new answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you're really using GCC (as tagged), dump the predefined preprocessor macros and and look for the types you care about. For example:

```
$ gcc -x c -E -dM /dev/null | grep SIZE
#define __SIZEOF_FLOAT80__ 16
#define __SIZE_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define __SIZEOF_INT__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_POINTER__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_LONG__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE__ 16
#define __SIZEOF_SIZE_T__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_WINT_T__ 4
#define __SIZE_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __SIZEOF_PTRDIFF_T__ 8
#define __SIZE_WIDTH__ 64
#define __SIZEOF_FLOAT__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_FLOAT128__ 16
#define __SIZEOF_SHORT__ 2
#define __SIZEOF_INT128__ 16
#define __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_DOUBLE__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_LONG_LONG__ 8
```

32-bit example:

```
$ gcc -m32 -x c -E -dM /dev/null | grep SIZE
#define __SIZEOF_FLOAT80__ 16
#define __SIZE_MAX__ 0xffffffffUL
#define __SIZEOF_INT__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_POINTER__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_LONG__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE__ 16
#define __SIZEOF_SIZE_T__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_WINT_T__ 4
#define __SIZE_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __SIZEOF_PTRDIFF_T__ 4
#define __SIZE_WIDTH__ 32
#define __SIZEOF_FLOAT__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_FLOAT128__ 16
#define __SIZEOF_SHORT__ 2
#define __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_DOUBLE__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_LONG_LONG__ 8
```

Comment: Carl, that's a good approach, thank you. I have ended up using/hacking the M4 macro suggested by Ian Abbott, because I think that repeatedly checking if the compiler fails when `sizeof()` is not the right one is a more general and reliable approach than using regular expressions, but this can work too.

Comment: Why would one rely on regular expressions with this?  If one were going to assume gcc and use the predefined macros then the natural way to get the values out is to use the preprocessor to expand the macros of interest.  Grepping for "SIZE" just helps you identify in advance which macros to probe.

Comment: I didn't really mean you had to use grep. I just did that to show some of them for reference.